# Error coming while creating UDF in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Does anyone know what's wrong with this code block.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfGetPoint]
(
    @UserID INT,
    @SqlCountry VARCHAR(1000)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Points INT
    SET @Points = 1
    DECLARE @RecordCount sysname
    IF @SqlCountry <> ''
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql
        N'SELECT @DynamicCount = COUNT(UserID) FROM Country WHERE UserID = '+@UserID+' AND LCValues IN (' + @SqlCountry + ')'
        ,N'@DynamicCount sysname OUTPUT'
        ,@RecordCount OUTPUT
        IF @RecordCount > 0
            SET @Points = @Points + 1
    END

    RETURN @Points
END
```

If i execute this i got following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure udfGetPoint, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate in the parameter setting of a stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(2000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT @DynamicCount = COUNT(UserID) FROM Country WHERE UserID = '+@UserID+' AND LCValues IN (' + @SqlCountry + ')'

EXEC sp_executesql
        @SQL
        ,N'@DynamicCount sysname OUTPUT'
        ,@RecordCount OUTPUT
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.given error has resolve but if execute stored procedure in which i used this UDF new error is coming: " Only functions and extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function."

Comment: @Sukhi: then you can't do this in a UDF.

Comment: what is extended stored procedure?

Comment: things like xp_cmdshell or sp_executesql

Comment: any other method that u can suggest.